# How to organize form_for helper to show data from different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models PriceGroup, PriceGroupLine and Item.

```
PriceGroup has fields - :id and :name. 

Item has fields - :id and :name. 

PriceGroupLine has fields - :id, :price_group_id, :item_id, :price
```

Associations:

```
PriceGroup has_many PriceGroupLines

Item has_one PriceGroupLine

PriceGroupLine belongs_to Item

PriceGroupLine belongs_to PriceGroup
```

I need to insert in PriceGroupLine model lines from PriceGroup show view. How I should organize form_for helper if I need to insert in PriceGroupLine:

```
item_id - items list organized with collection_select helper
price_group_id
price of item
```

I am using this code on view but I am not able to insert it:

```
<%= form_for @price_group, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <label>Товар</label> 
    <%= f.collection_select(:id, Item.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: "form-control"}) %> 
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <label>Цена</label> 
    <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %> 
  </div> 
  <%= f.submit "Добавить", class: "btn btn-default" %> 
<% end %>
```

And one more question about the associations. At the beginning i had associations like:

```
PriceGroup has_many PriceGroupLines

PriceGroupLine has_many Items

Item belongs_to PriceGroupLine

PriceGroupLine belongs_to PriceGroup
```

But this associations didn't work correctly when i tried to get :name field from Item model like this:

```
<% @price_group.price_group_lines.each do |price_group_line| %>
  <%= price_group_line.item.try(:name) %>>
  <%= price_group_line.price %>
<% end %>
```

I changed associations and all worked. Now `PriceGroupLine belongs_to :item` and `Item has_one :price_group_line`. But it is logical to assume that ITEM is belongs to PriceGroupLine (PRICEGROUPLINE contains ITEM). Am I wrong?

UPDATE
Almost there :)) Here is a screenshot of my form.

Code of show view PriceGroup:

```
<%= form_for @price_group, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :price_group_lines do |price_group_line| %>
        <%= render partial: "price_group_line_fields", locals: { f: price_group_line } %>
    <% end %>
  .links
     <%= link_to_add_association "Добавить", f, :price_group_lines %>
<% end %>
```

Code of partial:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label>Товар</label>
    <%= f.collection_select(:item_id, Item.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <label>Цена</label> 
    <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %> 
 </div>
```

[image: show.html.erb]

In footer Helper makes fields for each record in database. I need only items list to select a proper item and blank field PRICE to enter the price. And some word .link appears.

Comment: Actually previously you had `PriceGroupLine has_many Items` so because of this `price_group_line.item.name` didn't work as `price_group_line` didn't have a single item, it had multiple of it. Now about the new associations they seems to be correct if they fulfill your needs. But still using them on the view if you facing any issues or errors then please post it so we can help you with that error.

Comment: This form not working and I have no ideas how fix it.
`<%= form_for @price_group, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>

   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Item</label>
      <%= f.collection_select(:id, Item.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
     </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Price</label>
      <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Add Item", class: "btn btn-default" %>
 <% end %>`

Comment: For the word `links` I have updated the question. And as it is form for the fields it shows existing fields too for editing.

Comment: How do I get a form to add a new values without showing existing fields? And this code `<%= link_to_add_association "Добавить", f, :price_group_lines %>` gives me a link `http://localhost:3000/price_groups/5#`

Comment: Did you use `cocoon` gem and included its js?

Comment: Yes. Every time I click on Add link new form appears on the page and new record not created in database

Comment: Okay new form appears on the page, you are nearby to your goal. Now check your model for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and also while submitting the form keep a eye on log, what params are coming from form and if there are any unpermitted parameters or something like that.

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for` exists. Ok, all works. But it works only in edit view page. I can't make it work in show view page. Thanks for answer, i will solve this problem later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will be needing nested form for this. Using the nested form you will be able to insert multiple `price_group_lines` from `price_group` form. I would suggest you to use gem like [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for this. What you need to do is:

**In form:**

```
<%= form_for @price_group, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :price_group_lines do |price_group_line| %>
    <%= render 'price_group_line_fields', f: price_group_line %>
  <% end %>
  <div class='links'>
     <%= link_to_add_association 'add price group line', f, :price_group_lines %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**In price_group_line_fields:**

```
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <label>Товар</label>
    <%= f.collection_select(:item_id, Item.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <label>Цена</label> 
    <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %> 
  </div>
```

And in your controller you will need to allow this in strong parameters:

```
params.require(:price_group).permit(:name, :price_group_lines_attributes => [:item_id, :price])
```

And in you `PriceGroup` model you need to write:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :price_group_lines
```

This is just a example and rough code using cocoon gem, you can find more options by searching rails nested form. The code may throw error which you can easily fix.

Hope this helps.